# Single Sign On using openSSO

Tags: java, opensso

i have a two web applications running in java wih weblogic server, both the applications have same user name and password, so i decided to use single sign on machanism for sharing the session.

Apart from openSSO configuration, policy agent installation, i have to write java code for redirect the particular page from one application to another application.

if anyone already implemented the single sign on with java, please send me java the part to control the user authentication.

Answer (score 2):

If OpenSSO is setup properly for both the weblogic instances, you can just redirect from one application to the other, you don't have to do anything else.